# Solid color display on VGA not working

Tags: verilog, clock, intel-fpga, vga

I'm trying to get VGA working on my Altera DE0 board using Verilog, but haven't had much luck. It has the same pins as a normal VGA interface except red, green, and blue are all 4 bits each. Here is the logic I've been trying to use to get a solid color to display:

```
module solid_color (clk, vga_h_sync, vga_v_sync, R, G, B);

input clk;
output vga_h_sync;
output vga_v_sync;
output [3:0] R;
output [3:0] G;
output [3:0] B;

reg [9:0] CounterX;
reg [8:0] CounterY;
wire CounterXmaxed = (CounterX==767);

always @(posedge clk)
if(CounterXmaxed)
  CounterX <= 0;
else
  CounterX <= CounterX + 1;

always @(posedge clk)
if(CounterXmaxed)
    CounterY <= CounterY + 1;

reg vga_HS, vga_VS;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
  vga_HS <= (CounterX[9:4]==0);   // active for 16 clocks
  vga_VS <= (CounterY==0);   // active for 768 clocks
end

assign vga_h_sync = ~vga_HS;
assign vga_v_sync = ~vga_VS;

assign R = 15;
assign G = 15;
assign B = 15;

endmodule
```

When I try running it, I just get a message on the monitor saying that this display mode is not supported.

This is adapted from http://www.fpga4fun.com/PongGame.html. However, this version claims to be designed for 640x480 displays whereas my monitor is 1280x1024. Is this the issue? If so, how would I adapt this to fit the increased monitor size? (the clock I'm using is 50 MHz)

EDIT: I added in a clock divider module as follows to change the initial clock signal to 25 MHz:

```
module divide_clock_by_two(in_clk, out_clk);

input in_clk;
output out_clk;
reg out_clk;

always @(posedge in_clk)
out_clk <= ~out_clk;

endmodule
```

However, the monitor now just shows a black screen, no message about an incorrect mode.

Comment: That page says "Using a 25MHz clock", so you need to halve the clock or double all your timings.

Comment: The clk input to that module is a "pixel" clock, not a system clock.  You need to provide the right frequency clock for the resolution you are using.

Comment: I tried changing `CounterX==767` to `CounterX==1535` and `CounterX[9:4]` to `CounterX[9:5]` to double the timings, but this did not work.

Comment: Majenko, would this mean changing the timings or changing the input clock itself? According to this page with pixel clock timings: http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing, I would need to have at least a 108 MHz clock to drive my display, but this can't be correct because I have seen the board driving the display with just its 50 MHz clock in demos.

Comment: I don't know what you're reading, but I see: "VGA 640x480@60 Hz Industry standard (pixel clock 25.175 MHz)" - that's the speed of clock you should be passing to *clk* - or thereabouts (most monitors allow a bit of leeway).

Comment: I'm reading the section under 1280x1024, which is the monitor I have.

Comment: That's the *native* resolution of your monitor, and isn't the *only* resolution you can run it at. It will support many many resolutions below that resolution, like when you first turn on your computer and it runs in 640x400 (or similar) mode. If you want to run at a higher resolution (which you don't need to) you will have to make big changes to your timing.

Comment: I added in a clock divider just now, see the edit for details.

Comment: I take it you don't have a scope to be able to check what your sync looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most VGA monitors will "calibrate out the DC offset" if you drive the RGB signals outside of the viewable area.

While it may not be your *only* or even most serious problem, this looks to be an issue in your implementation (you drive constants), so try adding logic to drive your color signals to black when outside the intended display rectangle.

Comment: I was about to comment that the R G and B must be "off", i.e., set to black, during all blanking periods. Then I read your answer :P

Comment: That was the issue. I changed the assignments of R, G, and B and now I have a pattern. Also credit to Majenko though for the 25 MHz clock, as that was also necessary.

Comment: Although, how would I change this for a constant display of colors? In other words, with these counters, how would I recognize from the clock signals to stop driving RGB signals?

Comment: Use logic on each count value to determine when that axis is within the display region.

Comment: But how do I determine what the display region is? I was under the impression that the x and y counters already took care of that by looping back when they hit the maximum value.

Comment: You should look at a timing diagram of actual video signals, but in short the beam is only on the display part of the time - the rest it is over scanning or retracing, and you should drive black.  If you get some "mode line" values from an X window configuration for Linux, you'll see the times expressed in terms of possible dot clocks for X, and lines for Y - instead of loading those into VGA registers, you'll need something similar for your design.  Your current logic looks a bit incomplete.

Comment: Going back to this, I'm still not sure how to exactly how to determine when the display part of the time is. I thought at first that it might be when hsync and vsync are not active, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: You need to look at some waveforms from the manual of an older quality monitor.  Or, as already suggested, look at some X11 modelines.  Even documentation of a TV signal would give you a start on understanding, as though the values are different the concepts are basically the same.